# Excel VBA Performance Coding Settings

Tags: vba, excel

I've been researching how to speed up my code in Excel VBA and I've come across the following settings which have been helpful. My question is: is it possible to set the following lines of code into one variable that I can set to On or Off to activate the entire list? I.e. something like

```
speedUpCode = On
```

would set all of the below settings and if it were set to Off it would reverse all of the below to True/xlCalculationAutomatic

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False 'note this is a sheet-level setting
```

Comment: Colin, welcome to S.O.  You might want to check out http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking where a number of people chat about tinkering with the back end of VBA.

Comment: Most people will simply call a sub that includes this code. You can pass true or false as a parameter and turn it on/off that way.

Comment: You could wrap the code in a SUB or FUNCTION. You could then call this as needed.

Comment: there is a problem with blanket setting all these at once (whether inside a sub or not), because there may be times when you want `.ScreenUpdating = False` but `.EnableEvents = True`, for example. That said, generally speaking, in your list `.ScreenUpdating, .DisplayStatusBar and .DisplayPageBreaks` can all be set together - but even then, there may be a time when you need the StatusBar to display a message...

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this (very basic):

```
Sub GoFast(Optional bYesNo As Boolean = True)
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = Not bYesNo
      .Calculation = IIf(bYesNo, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
  End With
End Sub
```

Call with `True` or no parameter to speed things up, then with `False` to reset.

The comments above about about possibly capturing the current state of the various settings so you can get back to the "original" state, and that not all settings are always appropriate to update depending on exactly what you're doing are all worth considering.

Comment: Although you state it is basic, this helps me out a ton as i'm trying to learn the best methods for laying out my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function to do this like so ...

```
Function speedUpCode(sStatus As String)

    If sStatus = "On" Then
      With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = False
         .DisplayStatusBar = False
         .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
         .EnableEvents = False
      End With

    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False 'note this is a sheet-level setting

Else if sStatus = "Off" then

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True 'note this is a sheet-level setting

 End Function
```

you can then use these to turn on and off

```
  speedUpCode "On"
  speedUpCode "Off"
```

However,  keep in mind that you are turning settings on and off -  you should probably check the status of these before changing them so that you can reset them to the original setting  rather then just turning them all off again
you could does this with static variables

Comment: While, technically this works, it will break on a `Worksheet_Change` Event if `speedUpCode` is `On`. And code will not do as expected.

Comment: I Just included the settings he wanted to change, if you want to speed up code, your probably not looking for user interaction at that time anyway

Comment: Perhaps ... but it's a warning that is *very much needed* in case the OP has no clue what the effects may be.

Comment: Thanks for the response and comments!

Comment: I know that the topic is quite old, but maybe my comment will help someone: today I noticed that sometimes (for quite short fast macros - when you would make them more "fluent") enabling/disabling DisplayStatusBar can slow down our macro. So make sure to do some testing e.g. using loops.